# How can I access the localhost/phpmyadmin because all day I got This site can’t be reached?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am using windows and trying to develop an app in php where I connect a database mySQL created on mySQL workbench. I connect with root and a saved pass. But it seems I cannot connect to the page afterwards.

I use Windows 10.

```
  <?php

define('db_user', 'what is the user?');
define('db_pass', 'mypass');
define('db_host', 'localhost');
define('db_name', 'movies');

&db_conn = mysqli_connect(db_host, db_user, db_pass, db_name);

if(!&db_conn){
    die('error connecting to database');
}
echo 'you have connected succesfully';
?>
```

My database is called movies. I don't know what is the user?

Comment: In mySQL workbench shows me that my database is on localhost:3306, and I think the user is root. But I still cannot make localhost:3306/phpmyadmin to work. Or even to access my php code the same way.

Comment: How do you try to access your PHP site and what is the output in your browser when you do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phpMyAdmin is not a database; it is just one of the tools you use to manage what is inside. Your database is MySQL, which should be started and listening on a particular port. The default is usually 3306 or for MariaDB 3307. When MySQL server is located on the same machine as your web server, you can connect via `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

If you haven't set up any users in you MySQL server, then the default usually is `root` with no password. Check your users using this command:

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.user;
```

The user must also be authorized for an access via either localhost or IP, whichever you use.

Then to open a connection to MySQL in PHP using the mysqli class, you would usually use this code:

```
<?php

// your connection code
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'movies');
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4');
```

Comment: I understand what you said, thank you, but how can I access now my web page or localhost? I wanna see if the connection went well with the database. At least to show me a blank sheet or sth.

Comment: type `localhost` in your browser's url bar. This really depends where in your web server you have created this PHP file. What is your web server? Where is your file?

Comment: My file is in a folder called PHP_DB on Desktop. I typed localhost in my browser bar and it opens Internet Information Services, I dont really know what to do from here.

Comment: Then you should google how to use IIS with PHP. I would recommend wampserver instead. If the file is on your desktop, you definitely can't access it via web server. It needs to be in a specific directory as directed by your web server's documentation.